# Three of a kind in dice game

Tags: java, list

I am working on creating a method that will calculate if I get three of a kind rolling 5 total dice. I have created something as you can see below but it doesn't seem to be working the proper way. The whole objective is to see if you have rolled 3 of the same numbers and then if you have, multiply that number by 10 and add it to your score. For example if you rolled 5,5,5,1,2 you would add 50 to your total score.

My idea was to create an ArrayList and parse through each number of dierolled and add it to the new ArrayList while along the way checking for duplicates and using a counter.

This is what I came up with but as I said it isn't really working out. If anyone sees how I could improve this or do it correctly please don't hesitate to chime in!

**NOTE:** Assume that dierolled is where the 5 dice you got are stored and that updateTotalScore is a method that updates your score in a score class.

```
public void rule2b(ArrayList<Integer> dierolled){
  ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int counter = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < dierolled.size(); i++){
     int b = dierolled.get(i);
     if (numbers.contains(b)){
        counter++;
     }
     numbers.add(b);
     if (counter == 3){
        score.updateTotalScore(b*10);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the dice have a fixed number of sides? Or do you need to deal with d6 and d20 etc?

Comment: @mypetlion the dice are 6 sided

Answer (score 1):

I'd stream the list, count the occurrences of each element, and check if any of them occurs more than three times:

```
public void rule2b(List<Integer> diceRolled) {
    score.updateTotalScore(
             diceRolled.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                               Function.identity(), 
                                               Collectors.counting()))
                       .entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .filter(e -> e.getValue() >= 3)
                       .mapToLong(e -> e.getKey() * 10L)
                       .sum()
    );
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is I haven't learned much of what streaming is or for the most part what this is doing..

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the answer from Mureinik@. But if you are not aware of java8 features yet, here's a simple solution without streams and lambdas

```
Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int element = list.get(i);
    if (count.get(element) == null) {
        count.put(element, 1);
    } else {
        count.put(element, count.get(element) + 1);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : count.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() >= 3) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        //If there will be only one element with occurrence more than 3, you can break here.
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Another version as the OP wants to use just an ArrayList.

```
Collections.sort(list); //Sort the list - O(nlogn)

int element = list.get(0); //Beware of IndexOutOfBoundsException - I assume empty list at the start of the method
int counter = 1; //To count number of times element has occurred

for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    int currentElement = list.get(i);
    if (element == currentElement) {
        counter++; //Previous and current element are same
    } else {
        counter = 1; //We have seen a new number
    }
    if (counter == 3) {
        System.out.println(element); //Printing the element that has occurred 3 times
        //score.updateTotalScore(element * 10);
    }
    element = currentElement;
}
```

Comment: Your second for loop is really throwing me off. Although I get the idea you have, is there a simple way to do it with possibly an ArrayList?

Comment: @S.Vono Your arraylist just has a sequence of numbers from which you cannot determine the frequency of the numbers. One way would be to sort the list and then you can iterate the array checking if the next element is equal to the previous

Comment: @S.Vono I've updated my answer with the approach I mentioned

Comment: Interesting that you have to sort before you can move forward. Why is that? What would be the issue with just starting with the numbers random and starting the counter at 0 or something?

Comment: @S.Vono That won't work. Say you have a list [1,2,1,3,1]. Either you need to sort it or create a map from this to know the frequency. You cannot manage this with just a counter. eg - when you encounter you make the counter as 1 and when we move to the next element 2 what will you do to the counter?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
int[] dice = new int[6];
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    int num = list.get(i);
    dice[num-1]++;
    if(dice[num-1] == 3) {
        score.updateTotal(num*10);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm getting an out of bound exception at the dice[num-1]++ line

Comment: Still getting the error.. it says "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9"